# Encryption and decryption with custom string key

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

I would like to encrypt and decrypt a byte array (1024 length) with AES encryption in C#, using a random IVKey (GenerateIV) and a custom key string (where its bytes would be gotten to use it in aes). The thing is that I would not like to use the managed class for AES, and therefore I would like to use AesCryptoServiceProvider.

I never worked with cryptographics and I don't know which key and blocksize should I use (same goes for mode and padding).

PD: This would be for encrypting the packets which would be sent over the socket. **Not to encrypt the socket**.

Comment: Is the key a password (typically weak) or a high entropy secret (at least 128 bits of entropy)?

Comment: @CodesInChaos The key is a unix timestamp as a string, which is not really high entropy.

Comment: That "key" is so weak that you can't use it to encrypt securely, no matter what you do.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I thought about using the key I told you so with that I can ensure the key is not repeated (this encryption would be for a socket server), and therefore the key is more difficult to find since it would change everytime you connect to the socket (connection timestamp). What would you recommend me to use as a non-repetitive but high entropy key that would be changed upon connection to the server socket?

Comment: If you're encrypting a network connection, why don't you simply use SSL/TLS?

Comment: I don't get your point. Pretty much every language has bindings to an SSL/TLS implementation.

Comment: @CodesInChaos SSL uses AES (in some cases). Why would I use SSL instead of AES to encrypt the transmissions in a server socket? It's not an HTTP server though. I asked for AES, anyway.

Comment: @AlbertoLópez You should use TLS because if you try yourself, you make oodles of mistakes, any of them can (nay will) lead to catastrophic issues with regards to the confidentiality and integrity of your plaintext. Using a key value that is distinguishable from random is just the *start* of your worries.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that TLS doesn't already offer? If you want to write your own, you'll need to figure out how to do a key-exchange, how to authenticate the server and how to do authenticated symmetric encryption. There are dozens of pitfalls when doing this, many of them fatal. You can either 1) Use TLS 2) Implement a relatively simple existing protocol, like CurveCP or noise. 3) Study cryptography for months and attempt to design your own 4) Just write some code, that's almost certainly fatally broken. It sounds like you want to go with option 4.